# MPMoviePlayerController custom frame size

Tags: ios, video, frame, mpmovieplayercontroller

I use MPMoviePlayerController for displaying a video. The problem is that I don't want to display the video in full screen, I just want to display it in a small view.

In full screen is working but when I add this line (to set the video frame) it doesn't work anymore.

```
_moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(250, 150, 500, 500);
```

Here is my code:

ViewController.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
```

ViewController.m

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
              @"http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov"];

_moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                 initWithContentURL:url];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:_moviePlayer];

_moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
_moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[_moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeFill];
_moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(250, 150, 500, 500);
[self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
[_moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
```

Any ideas? or maybe MPMoviePlayerController is not the right object?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

skipp the line [_moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingMofeFill] . this line does not allow to you to show your video within the RECTMAKE because this has to fill complete screen .